# Retorno query via ajax laravel

Tags: laravel

Boa noite, alguém por favor poderia me ajudar nisso:
fiz um select e dei um "get()" no fim para pegar os resultados, passei os mesmos em um array que estou pegando numa function via ajax:

```
$table = DB::table('empenho as emp')
                ->join('gestora', 'emp.unidGestId', '=', 'gestora.id')
                ->join('gestora_tipo', 'gestora.tipoId', '=', 'gestora_tipo.id')
                ->join('despesa', 'emp.fichaOrcId', '=', 'despesa.id')
                ->join('pessoa', 'emp.fornecedorId', '=', 'pessoa.id')
                ->join('sub_elemento', 'emp.subElementoId', '=', 'sub_elemento.id')
                ->join('fonte', 'emp.fonteId', '=', 'fonte.id')
                ->join('siops', 'emp.siopsId', '=', 'siops.id')
                ->join('cbo', 'emp.cboId', '=', 'cbo.id')
                ->select('gestora_tipo.nome as a', 'emp.nrEmpenho as b', 'emp.date as c', 'emp.hora_insc as d',
                         'emp.valor as e', 'pessoa.nome as f', 'sub_elemento.codSubElem as g', 'despesa.valor as h',
                         'fonte.descricao as i', 'emp.historico as j', 'emp.tipo as k', 'siops.descricao as l',
                         'cbo.descricao as m', 'emp.folha as n')->get();

    $header = ['Gestora', 'Número', 'Data', 'Hora', 'Valor', 'Credor', 'SubElemento',
        'Despesa', 'Fonte', 'Historico', 'Tipo', 'Siops', 'CBO', 'Folha'];

    return ['Tipo' => 'Empenho', 'header' => $header, 'table' => $table, 'id' => $id];
```

No entanto eu não estou conseguindo mostra o resultado contendo os campos preenchidos com os valores do banco de dados, quando eu faço um for no ajax ele até pega a variável $header, mas não pega a $table, não consigo fazer esse retorno funcionar, alguém poderia me dizer no que eu estou errando?

```
function retornaEmpenho(json){
var result= $('<div>');
for(var i = 0; i < json.header.length; i++)
{   
    var divInner = $('<div>');
    divInner.addClass(json.header[i]);
    divInner.append(json.header[i]+': '+json.table[i]);
    result.append(divInner);
}
```

Quando eu faço o for jogando pra dentro os campos com os valores, o header funciona(claro), mas a $table não me retorna o certo, apenas um valor "undefined", alguém me ajude por favor ! Grato desde já.

Comment: Colega tente fazer um print_r da *$table* e fazer um for com o php (*foreach $table as $t echo $t->a*) para imprimir os dados se funcionar ajuste sua função em ajax.

Comment: Minha $table não está me retornando nada, totalmente vazia, parece que o problema está nela, mas não consigo entender o por que disso nem a onde estou errando.

Comment: Coloque o *select* antes dos join, teste com uma tabela e vá adicionando os joins.

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVIDO]

um dos campos não deixava me retornar, e mesmo assim quando começou a retornar me retornava um objeto, então fazendo um mapeamento do objeto transformando em array tudo se resolve.
Grato !

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.header.length; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < json.table.length; j++)
    {
    var arr = $.map(json.table[j], function(value){
        return [value];
    });
}
    var divInner = $('<div>');
    divInner.addClass(json.header[i]);
    divInner.append(json.header[i]+': ');
    divInner.append(arr[i]);
    result.append(divInner);
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```